# Unable to Read Cookie values from Newman - Jenkins CI

Tags: javascript, jenkins, postman, newman

Calling an API and obtaining the **Cookie** from **response body** is made possible through **Interceptor** in **Postman**.

Did it through this way: `https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/how-read-cookie-value-postman-request-chaining-ishan-girdhar-oscp`

But if I try to implement the same from **Newman** command line, It gives me an error, since there was no interceptor involved in CI (POSTMAN + JENKINS)

Tried to go through this link but It didn't help a lot: `https://github.com/postmanlabs/newman/issues/242`

Please suggest me a way to read cookies while running through Newman!

Many Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Use newman as Node JS module instead of from the command line.

The cookies are available in the object sent into the "request" event.

```
const newman = require('newman');

newman.run(options,callback)
.on('request',function(err,args) {
  console.log(args.response.cookie);
})
```